# Execute a short code on a image click?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, shortcode

Not sure to post here or webmasters, I apologize if I got wrong.

Does anyone know of a way to execute a short code on a image click?

I can not find anything on how to do this

Edit: My apologizes

Yes Shortcode means wordpress shortcode

Comment: have your tried <img src='...' onclick='myFunc(this);'>

Comment: is this a wordpress shortcode you are looking for? if so, you should tag your question with `wordpress` and `shortcode`

Comment: just so you know, Wordpress shortcodes are `php` functions that get replaced before the page has left the server, so trying to execute one with `javascript` would seem to be an impossibility...

Comment: I wouldn't say its an impossibility.  I would say you can achieve this with an AJAX request somehow, unfortunately I do not know AJAX.

Comment: what exactly should the shortcode do?

Answer (score 1):

==== Template page ====

```
<script> 
function executeShortCode() {
   var url="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/yourAjaxPage.php";
   jQuery.post(url,function(data){
   console.log(data);
   });


}
</script>
```

==== Ajax page ====

```
//yourAjaxPage.php
<?php echo do_shortcode('[yourshortcode]'); ?>
```

Comment: in this case the shortcode is already shown inside the script...so if called by javascript is doesnt pop up or something

Comment: Hello Arkaaprava, I added `function executeShortCode() {
   <?php echo do_shortcode('[yourshortcode]'); ?>` to customfunctions.php as well as `Header Scrips` and added a image to `<img src="someimage.png" onclick="executeShortCode()" /> ` and placed on a page but when I click the image nothing happens

Comment: @Tim  Try to execute shortcode using ajax. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because I just couldn't find answers online to my own question on this, I thought I'd post my solution. Using wp_localize_script to load my shortcodes, here is my example:

```
// PHP (in functions.php)
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_add_scripts' );
function custom_add_scripts() {
wp_register_script( 'my_new_js_callname', plugins_url( '/js/filename.js' , __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0.0', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_new_js_callname' );
}


add_action ('template_hook', 'custom_function_name');
function custom_function_name() {

// Because I used if/else statements in my JS, I loaded individual IDs into the array.

$examplea = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="118"]');
$exampleb = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="119"]');
$examplec = do_shortcode('[add_to_cart id="120"]');

$array = array( 
                'examplea' => $examplea,
                'exampleb' => $exampleb,
                'examplec' => $examplec,
        );


wp_localize_script( 'my_new_js_callname', 'callword', $array );
```

Then, on image click or any other JS event you are using do:

```
// JS (in filename.js)
<script>
document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function (){
    $("#show").html( callword.examplea );
  }
</script>
```

Then the shortcode is executed on my HTML page in there area where I have:

```
<div id="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get image element by it's id and attach the handler at `onclick` event something like

**html**

```
<img id="myImg" src="" />
```

**JS**

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('myImg').onclick = function (){
     //execute your short code here.
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that the OP means "short code" in the literal sense... It seems to be some sort of [Wordpress functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/shortcode/info)

Comment: intresting idea. have to be tested